# Сохранение форматированного текста в базе данных

Tags: html, база-данных

Есть блог. В блог пишутся посты. Пост - форматированный текст + картинки.
Я хочу сохранять форматированный текст в базе данных.

Нормально ли это сохранять html-куски в базе?
Лучше ли прибегнуть к Markdown\reStructedText?
Как такая задача решается в WordPress, Joomla, Drupal?

Answer (score 2):

> Нормально ли это сохранять html-куски в базе?

нормально. при занесении в базу пропускайте текст с тегами через [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: я с пайтоном работаю)

Comment: @Антон Феоктистов, ну тогда через пайтоноподобную функцию пропускайте =)